# Везунчик — русизм чи питоме?

Tags: іменники, росіянізм

У [Тлумачному словнику української мови](http://eslovnyk.com/%D0%92%D0%95%D0%97%D0%A3%D0%9D%D0%A7%D0%98%D0%9A) подано:

> **ВЕЗУНЧИК** **-а**, *ч. розм.*
>   Те саме, що щасливчик.

В [Практичному пораднику](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Vakulenko_Tetiana/Ukrainska_mova_Praktychnyi_poradnyk.pdf) знаходимо:

> Похідні **«везунчик»**, «везение» з російської правильно перекладати словами **«щасливчик»**, «фортуна», «щастя».

Але біля слова **везти** у [Словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/vezty) немає позначки *розм.*:

> **Везти**
>
> 2. *неперех., безос.,* кому. Щастити, фортунити. *— Не везе, брат, мені, ні в чому на світі не везе!* (Панас Мирний, I, 1954, 276)

Тоді чи є **везунчик** русизмом? Якщо так, то як бути з **везти**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все правильно, в СУМі-11 справді такої позначки у статті "везти" немає. Однак у **[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=196528&page=266)** є словникова стаття, що напряму стосується слова, про яке запитуєте:

> **ВЕЗУ́НЧИК**, а, ч., ***розм***. Пестл. до везу́н.
>
> Військлікар, який робив операцію, каже, що я везунчик. Тепер здоров'я моє піде на поправку (з публіц. літ.);
>
> Про людину, що домоглася успіхів, кажуть: везунчик (з газ.).

Далі шукаємо ще й ту статтю, до якої є відсилання:

> **ВЕЗУ́Н**, а́, ч., ***розм***. Той, кому часто щастить.

Отже, обидва слова є зафіксованими, однак містять позначку *розмовне*.

До речі, у цьому ж [Пораднику](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Vakulenko_Tetiana/Ukrainska_mova_Praktychnyi_poradnyk.pdf) знайшла ще таке:

> **Везти**  —  в  українській  мові  у  значенні  «фортунити,  таланити,  щастити»  **вживається  рідко,**  ***лише  в  художньому  та розмовному  стилях***;  в  усіх  стилях  це  слово  вживається  зі значенням  «пересувати,  переміщати  за  допомогою  певного транспортного засобу».

Таким чином, слово *везунчик* - зафіксоване у словниках і є *не русизмом* (хоча у російській справді це слово активно побутує), однак вживається лише у двох стилях: розмовному та художньому. Щодо використання, то тут обмежене у значенні "таланити", оскільки українська мова має декілька варіантів цього значення: щастити, таланити, фортунити.